# Property 'firebase' does not exist on type { production: boolean; }

Tags: angular, firebase, heroku, environment-variables, firebase-hosting

So I was trying to build and deploy my Angular 4 app for production on both Firebase and Heroku, but I have come across the error as follows:

> ERROR in /Users/.../... (57,49):  Property 'firebase' does not exist
> on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

It occurs when I run `ng build --prod`, and my deployment servers are working perfectly fine. Here is my **app.module.ts** file, for reference:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Ng2ScrollimateModule } from 'ng2-scrollimate';
import { Ng2PageScrollModule } from 'ng2-page-scroll';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LogoComponent } from './logo/logo.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './info/info.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { DividerComponent } from './divider/divider.component';
import { ProficienciesComponent } from './proficiencies/proficiencies.component';
import { ProficiencyComponent } from './proficiency/proficiency.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project/project.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './resume/resume.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { LoadingComponent } from './loading/loading.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LogoComponent,
    InfoComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    DividerComponent,
    ProficienciesComponent,
    ProficiencyComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    ProjectComponent,
    ResumeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    LoadingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    Ng2ScrollimateModule,
    Ng2PageScrollModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

**environment.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: 'project.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://project.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'project',
    storageBucket: 'project.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
  },
};
```

After scouring StackOverflow and GitHub for possible solutions, there seem to be no developers who have encountered this exact error and published their findings, so I was wondering whether anyone knows how to go about solving this issue. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What does your `environment` import looks like?

Comment: @echonax Let me update the question for you with my code.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

When you run `ng build --prod` angular-cli will use the `environment.prod.ts` file and your `environment.prod.ts` files `environment` variable doesn't have the `firebase` field hence you are getting the exception.

Add the field to
`environment.prod.ts`

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: 'project.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://project.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'project',
    storageBucket: 'project.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
  },
};
```

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver. All I had to do was replicate my `environment.ts` code into my `environment.prod.ts` file. Then, I simply ran: `ng build --prod` and `firebase deploy`.

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos glad I could help :-)

Comment: I agree, now I get firebase is not part of .... while I added it in both environement

Comment: If you are building as prod, you need to add your config to the environment.prod.ts.This worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

My approach is to merge common environment object with prod one. Here's my **environment.prod.ts**:

```js
import { environment as common } from './environment';

export const environment = {
  ...common,
  production: true
};
```

So common environment object acts as an overridable default for all other environments.

Comment: This approach looks good to me but not sure why Angular 7 cli shows warning,  ** WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\environments\environment.ts -> src\environments\environment.ts **

Answer (score 3):

I hate duplicates in code
so let's create a separate file named `environments/firebase.ts` with content

```
export const firebase = {
    //...
};
```

the usage

```
import {firebase} from '../environments/firebase';
//...
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebase)
```

all is clear as for me

Comment: So how will this overcome the problem that when ng build --prod is called, it will include this file and when ng serve is called, it will call the other?

Comment: @echonax yes i see it in `main.<hash>.js` file

Comment: I don't know what that means but let me put it this way; when OP calls ng serve, angular-cli will look for `environment.ts` and when `ng build --prod` is called, angular-cli will look for `environment.prod.ts`. By doing it like your answer, both prod and development environment will use the same config.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error because I had misspelled 'firebase' as 'firebas'

*firebas: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project",
    storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  }*

Answer (score -12):

Make sure there is no gap between `firebase` and `:`.

That is, it should be `firebase:`, not `firebase :`.

Comment: I see some people down voted this answer. However, in my case this answer fixed the issue I was facing. Thanks!