# push a Angular5 application with firebase db to GitHub

Tags: firebase, github, deployment, angular5

I have created an application using Angular5 and it is hosted with firebase database. I wanted to push my app into GitHub and I created a repository and pushed successfully.

But when I download it and run following commands "npm install" and "ng serve --open" but it doesn't display my app and display the starting page of newly creating project.

What should I do to get my application correctly or to deploy it correctly ??

Comment: Would need more information, did you push those changes and how did you checkout the code from git repo?

Comment: I checked it by downloading the repository as a zip file. 
I pushed after completing my application.

Comment: No, you should checkout and not download, use the command git clone and the url to repository. Either ways you would need to add more details like why the application doesn't display the starting page, are you seeing any errors in the browser etc. The more information you provide, the more easy it would be to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you vimukthi, sure I'll try with cloning url. When I run application after downloading, it doesn't give any error but it shows the app.component.html view of every new project.

Comment: I was succeeded, got help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033079/property-firebase-does-not-exist-on-type-production-boolean

Comment: Added the field to environment.prod.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added the field to environment.prod.ts

It should be as follow,

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project",
    storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  }
};
```

After that

```
 1. ng build --prod
           2. npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
           3. git add .
           4. git commit -m"first commit"
           5. git remote add origin git@github.com:yourinfo/yourgit.git
           6. git push -u origin master
           7. ng build --prod --base-href="https://YourUserName.github.io/Repo-Name/"
           8. angular-cli-ghpages
```

If all goes well, it will respond with successfully published!