# error TS2339: Property 'dialogflow' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'

Tags: angular, firebase, dialogflow-es, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to build a chatbot using Angular 7 and DialogFlow,but when I will deploy it to firebase, I got an error

> ERROR in src/app/chat/chat.service.ts(18,33): error TS2339: Property
>   'dialogflow' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

when I run `ng build --prod`

This is my chat.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript/es6/ApiAiClient';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export class Message {
  constructor(public content: string, public sentBy: string){}
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {

  readonly token  = environment.dialogflow.angularBot;
  readonly client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken: this.token });
  conversation = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>([]);

  constructor() { }

  update(msg: Message){
    this.conversation.next([msg]);
  }

  converse(msg: string){
    const userMessage = new Message(msg, 'user');
    this.update(userMessage);

    return this.client.textRequest(msg)
      .then(res => {
        const speech = res.result.fulfillment.speech;
        const botMessage = new Message(speech, 'bot');
        this.update(botMessage);
      });
  }

  talk(){
    this.client.textRequest('Who Are You!')
      .then(res => console.log(res));
  }
}
```

How to make it fix? Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

For production environment.ts will be replaced by environment.prod.ts

Add your angularBot properties in your environment.prod.ts

Check this also: https://indepth.dev/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist

Answer (score 0):

When you run ng build --prod angular-cli will use the environment.prod.ts file and your environment.prod.ts files environment variable doesn't have the dialogflow hence you are getting the error.

Check this out for more details - [Property 'firebase' does not exist on type { production: boolean; }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033079/property-firebase-does-not-exist-on-type-production-boolean?rq=1)